# Using an EL variable in a javascript file with Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, el

I use Spring Mvc and I would like to use an EL variable (e.g. `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`) in a `.js` javascript file.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a template that contains the JS, and pass the contextPath as a variable that's interpolated into the template.

```
@RequestMapping(value="path/to/handler", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="text/javascript")
public ModelAndView getJs(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
  return new ModelAndView("/path/to/js/", "contextPath", contextPath);
}
```

<strike>But why do you need to do this? The context path is available in the client as well</strike>

Edit:

For this to work you might have to set up a [ViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) so that the template is processed (if you don't have one already).

In the page you just include the script as normal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/handler" />
```

Comment: Thanks ebaxt! Ummm, what do you mean by: _The context path is available in the client as well_?

Comment: Well, not sure what your exact needs are, but in many cases you can access that information you need in JS in `window.location`. If you need to creates links etc, have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I just used the contextPath as an example. I might use another variable...

Comment: One last question: how do I use the above generated template? If say I have a `@RequestMapping("myJs.js")` above, can I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="myJs.js"/>` in my html?

Comment: I see. Any idea how to set up a view resolver for javascript though?

Comment: The ViewResolver is basically a hook that enables the template engine of choice to create the view (JS file in your case) on the server. The output of the template engine is then sent to the client. It's not specific to JS, it can return HTML, XML, JSON etc. There are many different template engines, personally I prefer FreeMarker, but JSP is probably the easiest to start with. Example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-example/

Comment: I myself use Thymeleaf (which I highly recommend you to try if you don't already know it - but I digress...). Do you mean I can use a Thymeleaf/FreeMarker view resolver for javascript? Maybe this is not relevant to my original question and I should open another post. Thanks to you anyway ebaxt.

Answer (score 2):

Another common way to achieve this is to declare your JSTL values (e.g. contextPath) in your calling JSP page inside a `<script>` tag by adding them to a global JS object, variable or initializing function. You can then reference these values in an external JS file that gets called by your original JSP page.

See: [this answer to "Using JavaScript within a JSP tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229776/249327)

Although it is a bit crude, it might be the only option if you are using a tool such as [JAWR](http://jawr.java.net/).