# JSP library that buffers JavaScript and appends to the end of page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tags

I have a JSP main page that includes multiple page fragments (header, main content, footer etc.). Those fragments contain some Javascript code that is related to them.

Right now the js in those files is at the end of them, wrapped in a jQuery `$(document).ready`.

Is there a JSP tag / library that I can use to "buffer" / queue all inline Javascript from those fragments and append it at the very end of the main document?

My wishful usage:

**main.jsp**

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<jsp:include page="main.jsp" />
...
<lib:js-out/>
```

**header.jsp**

```
   <h1 id="hi">Hi there</h1>
   <lib:js-buffer>
       $("#hi").coolAnimation();
   </lib:js-buffer>
```

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229726/using-javascript-within-a-jsp-tag) be very useful ;)

Comment: @DanteSparda Doesn't seem useful, why would you think so? I dont want to use JS in a tag, I want to use a tag to deffer inclusion in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own js-buffer tag-lib to save those all to a file which you include at the end.  But then, it seems problematic to me. Each time those pages are included its writing the file...which is a waste of resources and could obviously result in write access violations under heavy traffic. Either that or you have to keep track somehow of the update dates on your jsp files and your include files that the tag-lib is creating.